# insmod: Invalid module format - How to verify version incompatibility or force?

Tags: kernel-modules

I am running a custom built kernel (4.8.15-rt10) and have been given a module that was built on the exact same kernel with the same .config (I provided everything).  When I use insmod to insert the module, I get there error "Invalid module format".  So first inclination is wrong kernel version, here are the results of modinfo compared with `uname -a`:

```
uname -a ==> 4.8.15-rt10 #5 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Oct 23 10:57:27 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
modinfo ==> vermagic: 4.8.15-rt10 SMP preempt mod_unload
```

As far as I can tell it's the same kernel, so what am I missing?  I read somewhere I can use modprobe --force to force it, but somehow I need to use depmod first?

Thanks

---

Output:

```
user@user:/usr/src/linux-4.8.15-rt10$ cat .config | grep 'CONFIG_PREEMPT'
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT__LL is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_RTB is not set
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_TRACER is not set
```

Comment: Looking closer, I'm thinking they built it without changing the Preemption model from 'Preemptible Kernel' to 'Fully Preemptible Kernel'

Comment: After `make menuconfig` check the `.config` file with `cat .config | grep 'CONFIG_PREEMPT'` what is the output? [you can edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/399973/edit)

Comment: Added above, although I don't have the .config that was used to build the supplied module.  I did, however, give them mine and ask them to use it.  I've contacted them to double check they used the same .config file.